# When is a php object null?

Tags: php

I have an object whose properties I haven't defined and yet none of the below checks return in favor of object being null.

Is an object only null when we assign it as null. I tried few and searched for other alternatives but none of them tell that the object is null rather opposite. So how do we check if an object is null, or all of the below ways are false ?

Or is an object never null since it holds properties even though they are not set.

```
class LinkedList implements DataStructure {


    public $head;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->head  = new Node;
        $this->tail = new Node;

        //checking all posibilities i am aware of
        echo "are you an object ? ".gettype($this->head);

        echo "<br/>are you null ? ".is_null($this->head);
        echo "<br/>are you empty ? ".empty($this->head);
        echo "<br/>are you null ? ". ($this->head === null);
        echo "<br/>what is your count ? ".count($this->head);
        echo "<br/>maybe you are not set ? ".isset($this->head);

    }
}
```

this is my Node class .. if it helps you guys help me

```
class Node {

    public $next;
    public $file;
    public $folder;
    public $parentDirectory;

}
```

The output of the above code is :

```
are you an object ? object 
are you null ?
are you empty ?
are you null ?
what is your count ? 1
maybe you are not set ? 1
```

Also a `var_dump($this->head)` returns this

```
object(App\Library\DataStructures\Node)#202 (4) {

  ["next"]=>
  NULL

  ["file"]=>
  NULL

  ["folder"]=>
  NULL

  ["parentDirectory"]=>
  NULL

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at PHP types:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

`object` is a type, and `null` is another type.

Here you are setting `$this->head` to an `object` `Node`. Nonetheless of what happens inside `Node` object, it is still an `object`.

If you set `this->head = null`, only then it would be considered of type `null`.

Comment: thank you for the information. But if so what is the proper way of checking if an object has only been declared and none of its properties have been defined ?

Comment: You can just check if it is `$this->head === new Node()`.